# Is it possible to use yarn-pnp with typescript/vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

yarn-pnp is awesome - no more node_modules!
But without node_models, typescript/vscode can't seem to resolve modules correctly.

Is there a way to make this work?
Thanks!

Comment: No way that I know of, but it's being discussed, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28289

Comment: thanks, @artem - I'll watch that thread.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes!

Typescript cli works out of the box in Yarn 2+, so you can just add the package:
`yarn add -D typescript`

and run the compilation:
`yarn tsc`

It is also possible to make VS Code work with PnP modules! You can use `@yarnpkg/sdks package (which is a part of Yarn 2+)

You can enable PnP support in VS Code via:
`yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`
This will generate `tssdk` and modifies your `.vscode/settings.json` to add TypeScript compiler-wrapper inside `tssdk` as a Workspace TypeScript compiler. You should run VS Code, open any TypeScript file and in the bottom right side of the window click on TypeScript version. Select `Use Workspace Version` from dropdown menu to actually use Workspace Compiler, its version has the suffix `-sdk`.

You might also want to install VS Code zip file support extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs
to be able to open source of your project dependencies, because Yarn 2 stores all the dependencies in zip files

You can also read official Yarn 2+ docs on Editor integrations here:
https://next.yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks

Comment: Hmm... looks to me it ignores @latest and installs only stable.

Comment: Noob question: do we have to run `yarn pnpify --sdk` every time we add, upgrade or remove a dependency? Because if yes, this is a major drawback of yarn v2.

Comment: You need to run `yarn pnpify --sdk` only when you add a new dependency, `typescript`, `eslint`, etc. The tool gets currently installed dependencies and generates wrappers for them, it needs to know what packages do you use, that need wrappers. When you remove or upgrade one of these deps, you don't need to run `yarn pnpify --sdk`. You might still want to do it when you upgrade `typescript`, so that VS Code showed correct version in status bar: `x.y.z-pnpify` one, otherwise it will show old, but everything will still work.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer, the cli syntax was changed only recently

Comment: I wish there was a solution for VS Code live share. Seems like guests aren't allowed to use the custom generated tsdk file.

Comment: Hi, but in my case I can't find so called `Use Workspace Version` as it only gives one choice that is `Use VS Code's Version (4.3.2)` while my yarn add(ed) ts is v4.1.6.

[Edit]: Following @Renfrew 's answer works for my case.

Comment: Finally! I ran into this problem, been searching all day now I found out this isn't a TypeScript error, but rather a Yarn + VS Code problem! Thank you so much for the easy solution!

Answer (score 5):

Add to @Viktor Vlasenko:

When I have a workspace and I create a typescript project inside the workspace,
the rule `typescript.tsdk` and `typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk` inside the `settings.json` of the new project may not work. In this case, You would not find `x.x.x-pnpify` when selecting the TypeScript Version.

The VS Code reported that `This setting cannot be applied in this workspace. It will be applied when you open the containing workspace folder directly.`

Therefore, after the step `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/pnpify --sdk vscode`, make sure those new rules in the `settings.json` are applied. You may need to open a new window and open the folder directly.

VS Code Version: 1.53.2

yarn Version: 2.4.0